# How to change X-axis format in plot

Tags: r

I have fit a linear model and I now doing a lack-of-fit test. If the model has a good fit, the residual deviance should follow a $\chi^2$ distribution. The model I just ran has a very poor fit, and now I want to show this visually. I have used the following R code to plot the value of the residual deviance and the $\chi^2$ distribution it should come from (under the hypothesis of good fit).

```
df <- 384162
resdev <- 750749
x <- seq(from=350000, to=800000, by=1)
y <- dchisq(x, df=df)
plot(x, y, type='l')
abline(v=resdev, col='red')
```

Everything is working fine, except now the X-axis values are displaying in scientific notation. How to I control the formating of the axis values? I understand it may be crowded if I use normal notation, so can I format labels something like `350k` for 350,000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at  function `axis`  help page. Something like the following should work:

```
axis(1, at = x <- seq(3.5e5, 8e5, by = 5e4),  labels = paste(x/1000, "k", sep = "" ))
```

Comment: @Daniel: if applying this, turn off the x-axis in the `plot()` call: `plot(x, y, type = "l", xaxt = "n")` and change the two `x` s so you don't overwrite the data you created to draw the plot.

Comment: This worked, except it plotted the new axis over the old one. How would I address this issue?